# Когда отписываться от Observable?

Tags: android, retrofit, rxjava

Доброго времени суток !

пытаюсь разобраться со связкой RxJava + Retrofit
в интерфейсе retrofit есть метод возвращающий Single

```
@GET
fun getPicture(@Url url: String): Single<ResponseBody>
```

подписываюсь так

```
viewModel.retrofitRepo.getPicture("https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/45?v=4")
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe (
        {result ->
            val bitmap = result.byteStream().use(BitmapFactory::decodeStream)
            binding.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
        },
        { error -> error.printStackTrace() })
```

картинка загружается, все ок, но ! 
когда мне вызывать dispose() для этого Disposable ?

читал что для этих целей можно использовать **CompositeDisposable**, но когда вызывать **compositeDisposable.dispose()** ? если в onDestroy() то мне кажется будет лишнее потребление памяти
к примеру пока фрагмент жив я сделал 100 запросов, соответственно в **CompositeDisposable** будет 100 бесполезных Disposable ...

мне кажется логичнее было-бы отписаться от Disposable при обработке onSuccess или onError, но как это сделать не пойму

если вообще ничего не делать то студия говорит "The result of `subscribe` is not used" и игнорировать это думаю не совсем правильно, как и использовать анотацию **@SuppressLint("CheckResult")**

буду рад разъяснениям !

Answer (score 1):

Подписывайтесь во `ViewModel` и складывайте `Disposable`  в `CompositeDisposable`. А `dispose()` вызывайте в `onСleared` методе `ViewModel`. Тогда запросы будут переживать смену конфигураций.